# Lost Premiere Project

Tags: after-effects, premiere-pro

I accidentally deleted my premiere project and after effect project including assets and auto-save folders. Permanently deleted from trash too. 
Is there a way to rebuild the project files from cache or anywhere else. I have copy of the assets - just need the project files. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using your computer right now. Every youtube video you see, and every webpage you visit is potentially overwriting the files you deleted, corrupting them.
2. Look for a computer technician that knows how to use an undelete program. A deleted file or folder is not deleted right away, it is only changed the name to something from

NameOfTheFolder to $ameOfTheFolder

so, an undelete program can potentially find those deleted files, by name, date, etc, and retrieve them, only if some other file has not written new information on the designated space for the previous file.

It might be necessary to use several undelete programs because sometimes they use different methods to retrieve information.

Part of the service might involve connecting the hard drive to another computer, so no normal computer process overrides more disk space.

3. Stop using your computer right now.